Flask & WordPress
I am planning on building a landing page for one of my projects using WordPress and hosted on Hostinger.
I have my main website program made through Python Flask.
If I want to host this whole website how would I do this?
My initial thoughts were to host the landing page on Hostinger WordPress and host the flask application on another hosting service (e.g. AWS). For example, I could make the landing page mydomain.com and host the flask as mydomain.com/subDomain and then link a button on the WordPress landing page to the mydomain.com/subDomain.
Is there a way you can host the flask application on Hostinger Wordpress itself or does anyone know of a better way of hosting/setting-up a website such as this?
Thanks.
